# Laravel Form::Select

Tags: forms, laravel, select, drop-down-menu

I am using dropdown menu to select the **site** as:

```
{{ Form::select('site', $sites, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Select a Site']) }}
{{ Form::label('site','site*') }}
```

I am storing the selected **site** in the database as `site_id`.
As this returns the index of the selected item from the list, so if the first item is selected the `site_id` would be stored as **0** in the database.

The problem here is, `site_id` is a foreign_key in my database and this is causing errors while matching it with the `column:id` of the `sites` table. As the `id` column generated by laravel migration scaffolding starts from **1** and the `site_id` returned by `Form::select` starts from **0**.

Is there anyway that the index returned from `Form::select` would start from **1**?

Or is there any other way to solve the problem?

Comment: Can you show how you are serving $sites to the blade?

Comment: $sites = Site::latest()->get(['name']);
And I am using the laravel compact('sites').

Comment: Try to use Site::latest()->get()->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray() This will change the index/value of the select to match the id of the item.

Comment: This solves the problem. Thanks @NMahurin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're getting the sites from DB, keep original IDs to solve the problem:

```
$sites = Site::pluck('name', 'id');
```

This code will generate a list of sites' names with real IDs:

```
[1 => 'Site name 1', 2 => 'Site name 2']
```

Comment: Thanks. But this would just change the id 0 to 1. And that way the site in the  index 0 and that in the index 1 would be stored as the same. Right?

Comment: @SijanBhattarai you've said you want it to be saved as 1 instead of 0. If it's not what you want, please try to explain what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: I have edited the question. I hope it is more clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have many solutions

First, just verify with the validation, site must not be 0 since your controller

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

/** ... */
$this->validate($request, [
   'site'=>['required',Rule::notIn([0])]
])
```

You can also check where you save Site model :

```
DB::transaction(function() use($request){
     /** mapping of site attribute */
     if($site->save())
     {

     }
}
```

You can also check since client side via JavaScript

```
{{ Form::select('site', $sites, null, ['id'=>'sites', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Select a Site']) }}
{{ Form::label('site','site*') }}


$("form input['type=submit']").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     if($('#sites').val() == 0)
     {
        alert('Please, select a site');
        return;
     }else{
         $(this).submit();
     }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to inset name without id you can use $sites = Site::pluck('name', 'name'); I hope this will work.